# one-time safe publication via a Java volatile

Tags: java, volatile

At this tutorial ([link](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-jtp06197/)) on Java's volatile declaration is this example:

```
public class BackgroundFloobleLoader {
    public volatile Flooble theFlooble;

    public void initInBackground() {
        // do lots of stuff
        theFlooble = new Flooble();  // this is the only write to theFlooble
    }
}

public class SomeOtherClass {
    public void doWork() {
        while (true) { 
            // do some stuff...
            // use the Flooble, but only if it is ready
            if (floobleLoader.theFlooble != null) 
                doSomething(floobleLoader.theFlooble);
        }
    }
}
```

It is said that the background thread is loading from a database so I think the author means the instantiation `new Flooble()` takes a significant amount of time.

To quote: `Without the theFlooble reference being volatile, the code in doWork() would be at risk for seeing a partially constructed Flooble as it dereferences the theFlooble reference.`

How can it be? I would have expected the opposite. That is, I would have expected that without the volatile declaration the thread invoking `doWork` method would be at risk of seeing the Flooble belatedly or never at all.

Comment: You could never see it, see it late and/or see it in an inconsistent state.

Comment: It seems instantiation must be complete (even if the database reading takes a long time) before the reference gets assigned. In that case I don't see why the object being referenced would be in an inconsistent state.

Comment: Precisely, your expectation is the sensible expectation but sadly if it was true Java would not be able to scale to a large number of concurrent CPUs effectively.

Comment: When neither volatile or synchronized are used, Java optimises the code for use on a single CPU.  Which means other CPUs may or may not see the data changes being made by that CPU.   Every time a CPU changes data locally within the CPU, it runs super fast.  Every time it has to share that change so that other CPUs can see the changes, it slows down A LOT.  And I cannot stress enough how much that slow down is.

Comment: You may interpret above to be at the Java language level of instructions.  Which can cause this confusion, there is a mismatch between the boundaries of a java instruction and the boundaries of the native cpu instruction.   This mismatch, combined with optimisations for speed mean that all guesses are off unless as to what will be visible/not visible when sharing data between cpus without using synchronized/volatile.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It can be caused by compiler reorderings. Compiler can inline `Flooble`'s constructor and change order of initialization of its fields and assigning reference to `theFlooble` variable.
Declaring `theFlooble` volatile prevents such reorderings.

See https://www.cs.umd.edu/~pugh/java/memoryModel/DoubleCheckedLocking.html

Comment: I'm surprised. Such a reordering feels almost like sabotage or at least an optimization bug.

Comment: @H2ONaCl it can feel like that at first.  But it starts to make a lot of sense when researching the history of hardware design.  Once upon a time CPUs could be made faster just by increasing the clock speed.  That "easy win" is no longer possible and to get further performance gains out of CPUs the hardware guys have to go increasingly parallel and pull some pretty clever tricks.   Java does an amazing job of isolating us programmers from these optimisations... most of the time.

Comment: @H2ONaCl Martin Thompson discusses a lot of this on his blog, which is an excellent read.   If you have the time, I recommend checkout out http://mechanical-sympathy.blogspot.co.uk.   http://mechanical-sympathy.blogspot.co.uk/2013/02/cpu-cache-flushing-fallacy.html is a good start for raising ones awareness of the differing issues.

Comment: @H2ONaCl it's not a sabotage or bug since it's documented. Memory model is just tradeoff between performance and simplicity at programmer's side. So we have to respect Java Memory Model.

Comment: Perhaps instead of disgust I should think of it this way: If I don't use volatile I introduce a visibility (latency in publishing) problem and the reordering optimization makes it worse. Since I do want to use volatile to get rid of the visibility problem there's nothing to worry about.

Answer (score 1):

> Compiler can inline Flooble's constructor and change order of initialization of its fields and assigning reference to theFlooble variable

I've seen this declared in blogs, SO posts, and numerous other places, but it directly contradicts the java language spec:

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-12.html#jls-12.5

That in essence states, barring any exceptions, the constructor will complete before a reference is returned. If you don't have a reference before the object is constructed, you can't see a partially constructed object anywhere. And if you inline the constructor, you better make sure no one else can see that reference, or you're violating the spec.

The one assembly decompilation I've seen that seems to show this was stated to have been generated by an ancient Symantec JIT compiler - not exactly official.

If someone could explain why a modern, approved, OpenJDK compiler can re-order writes to expose a reference to a partially created object, and why that doesn't contradict the spec, I'll bite, but until, this all looks like a bunch of hand-waving generalizations based on experiences with other compilers and specs (and, note, I don't mean revealing a partially constructed object by leaking the this pointer out to an external class - if you do that, you only have yourself to blame).

Comment: I would like to see a good answer to this.  My understanding agrees with this answer, but also that tutorial is written by Brian Goetz who literally wrote the book on Java concurrency.